# SQLite no hace el Update

Tags: java, android, sqlite, update

Tengo un problema para `Updatear` un valor de `SQLite` puesto que cuando almaceno el dato le pongo el valor 1 y a ese dato luego lo quiero modificar a 0. Pero, no sucede nada. No entiendo cual es el problema con mi código ya que ni siquiera sale alguna clase de error.

Método para actualizar:

```
private ContentValues mapaSiguiendo(SeguirManga sm){
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(PaginasTabla.NOMBRE_MANGA, sm.getNombre());
    cv.put(PaginasTabla.URL_MANGA, sm.getUrl());
    cv.put(PaginasTabla.URL_IMAGEN, sm.getUrlImagen());
    cv.put(PaginasTabla.CONTADOR_CAPITULOS, sm.getContador());
    cv.put(PaginasTabla.BIT_SEGUIR_NO, sm.getValorSeguir());
    return cv;
}

public void actualizar(SeguirManga sm, Context actividad) {
    try{
        this.openWriteableDB();
        String where = PaginasTabla.ID_ELEMENTO + " = ?";
        db.update(PaginasTabla.TABLA_SEGUIR, mapaSiguiendo(sm), where, new String[]{String.valueOf(sm.getId())});
        db.close();
        Toast.makeText(actividad, "Modificado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }catch(Exception sqlException){
        Toast.makeText(actividad, "Error: " + sqlException.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Actividad con el evento:

```
    dejarDato.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dejarMetodoDaato();
        }
    });

private void dejarMetodoDaato(){
    PaginasSQL paginasSQL = new PaginasSQL(TMOnlineMangaSeleccion.this);
    seguirManga.setValorSeguir(0);
    paginasSQL.actualizar(seguirManga, TMOnlineMangaSeleccion.this);
}
```

El valor se queda en 1 siempre, ¿Cuál es mi error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este caso te sugiero validar la actualización cuando usas el método [**update()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#update(java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D)) de esta forma para tener más detalle del problema:

```
public void actualizar(SeguirManga sm, Context actividad) {
    try{
        this.openWriteableDB();
        String where = PaginasTabla.ID_ELEMENTO + " = ?";
    int actualizacion = db.update(PaginasTabla.TABLA_SEGUIR, mapaSiguiendo(sm), where, new String[]{String.valueOf(sm.getId())});
    
    switch(actualizacion ){
         case -1:  // Error actualizando
          Toast.makeText(actividad, "Ocurrió un error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         break;
        case 0: // No se actualizó nada 
          Toast.makeText(actividad, "No se actualizo ningún registro", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         break;
         default:
          Toast.makeText(actividad, "Se actualizaron " + actualizacion  + " registros", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         break;
    }
        db.close();       
    }catch(Exception sqlException){
        Toast.makeText(actividad, "Error: " + sqlException.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Me parece que el problema es simplemente que no tiene valor que actualizar, revisa que `sm.getId()` contenga el valor de un Id que en realidad se encuentra en la tabla.

Comment: Pues sí, el problema es que no me está llegando el id y no se porqué

Comment: :-) hehe que bien que encontraste la causa, acostumbra usar el valor que retorna update() para revisar que sucede al actualizar, saludos.